# no newlines in generated CSV

Tags: javascript, csv

In my page I am writing the following script to generate CSV to download. 
My string 'str' has some new line char's "\n" but generated csv is all in one line. am I missing anything?

```
            var fileContent = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8," + str;
            var a = document.createElement('a');
            a.href = fileContent;
            a.download = filename;
            var e = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
            e.initMouseEvent('click', true, false, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
            a.dispatchEvent(e);
```

Comment: can you show the sample of your str?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to convert the data to base64

in most browsers, it's as simple as

```
var fileContent = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8;base64," + btoa(str);
```

> However, if you have a Unicode string, this will fail. Consider this instead - source = http://mdn.beonex.com/en/DOM/window.btoa.html#Unicode_Strings

```
function utf8_to_b64( str ) {
    return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(str)));
}
var fileContent = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8;base64," + utf8_to_b64(str);
```